# set a symbol marker with highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, highcharts

highchart has an option which will let me set a marker to certain value.

highchart doc:

```
...
     data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, {
        y: 26.5,
        marker: {
           symbol: 'url(/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
        }
     }, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
...
```

As you can see, the position 26.5 gains a png image as its marker.

My question is: How can I set it to a certain value from my array?

```
$.getJSON('ajax/lineChart.ajax.php', function(data) {        
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        var series = { 
            data: [ {
                y: 0,
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(img/fail.png)'
                }
            }], //data array for new series
            name: key,
            marker: {
                    symbol: 'square'
                }
        }; 
        series.data = value;
        options.series.push(series); // <-------- pushing series object
    });
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);  
});
```

i tried this, but nothing appeared. The chart ran without the marker.

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
series.data = value;
```

overwrite whatever you wrote in

```
var series = { 
        data: [ {
```

I am not sure what you have in the "data" variable, but assume its is as [key:[val1,val2,...],...], try replace "series.data = value" with the following:

```
var list= new Array();
foreach(var v as value){
   if (v==0){ //or what ever condition you need to use a different mark 
      var m={
            y: v,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(img/fail.png)'
            }};
      list.push(m);       
   } 
   else{
      list.push(v);
   }
}
series.data = list;
```